# How to tell Builder to not to escape values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, builder

```
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
 => <inspect/> 
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > xml.foo '<b>wow</b>'
 => "<inspect/><foo>&lt;b&gt;wow&lt;/b&gt;</foo>" 
ruby-1.8.7-p249 >
```

Builder is escaping the content and is converting the b tag into an escaped value. How do I tell Builder to not escape it? I am using Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Builder::XmlMarkup#<<`

```
xml.foo do
  xml << '<b>wow</b>'
end
```

Comment: awesome. It too me much longer to type the question. :-)

Comment: I can accept an answer in 8 minutes even though I got the answer in 2 minutes. :-)

Comment: How could I do something like  ´xml.libro(
      resumen:  "blabla",
      sinopsis: xml << '&resumen_libro')´ ? because this doesn't work