# How to build a builder dynamically with escaped values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, builder

Now I know how to build xml without escaping values. [How to tell Builder to not to escape values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693036/how-to-tell-bulider-to-not-to-escape-values)

However I need to build tags dynamically.

Desired result

```
<bank_info>Chase</bank_info>
```

What I have is

```
attr = 'bank_info'
builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
builder.attr { |x| x << 'bank_info' } # does not work
```

I can try making the whole thing as a giant string and eval that. But evaling is not that safe. Is there a better option that I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the simplest way to call a method for which you have a name is to use `send` or `__send__`. Here:

```
builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
builder.__send__("bank_info") do  # same effect as:  builder.bank_info do
  builder << "Chase"
end
```

BTW, there is the variant `public_send`, in case you want to insure you are not calling a private method. It's only in Ruby 1.9, you can `require "backports"` to use it in Ruby 1.8.

Note: in this case, `send` doesn't work, as pointed out by @KandadaBoggu, because Builder overrides it; you must use `__send__`.

Comment: @marc Your code will generate `<send>bank_infoChase</send>` as markup. It looks like builder is overriding all the default methods. I worked around it by using `tag!` method.

Comment: That should teach me not to test my code! I wonder if `__send__` is also overriden... Anyways, `tag!` is the way to go

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned that I want my data to be unescaped and tag! escapes it. That is why in my example I resorted to << .

Comment: Ah, so I checked and `__send__` is what you want to use. Answer updated

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 builder.tag! "bank_info", "Citi"
```

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned that I want my data to be unescaped and tag! escapes it. That is why in my example I resorted to << .